# How to access Flutter plugin pubspec.yaml programatically?

Tags: flutter, plugins, package-info

Lots of questions regarding how to access the pubspec.yaml, but only solutions for Flutter apps. This questions targets **Flutter plugins** for which a package like `package_info_plus` will not return the version from pubspec.yaml, but rather from the corresponding example app.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Project option and then track below way:

Project>External Libraries>Flutter Plugins

You can see them like in the below screenshot:

[image: related image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for how to access the pubspec.yaml from code. I edited the question title to clarify.